# Navbar hide on click menu item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem but I don't know-how.
My problem is, that when I click on some item, router-view is changed correctly, but the menu is still opened. I want to close it after a click.
     `This is my navbar component`

```
    <template>
      <nav class="navbar-main">
        <!-- navigation button -->
        <div class="navbar-button" :class="{'is-active': isActive}" @click="isActive = !isActive">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-menu" :class="{'is-active-menu': isActive}">
          <ul class="primary-menu">
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
              <router-link to="/" exact activeClass="link-active" class="nav-menu--link" tag="a">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home
              </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
              <router-link to="/about" activeClass="link-active" class="navbar-item" tag="a">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>About
              </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
              <router-link to="/resume" activeClass="link-active" class="navbar-item" tag="a">
                <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>Resume
              </router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-menu-item">
              <router-link to="/portfolio" activeClass="link-active" class="navbar-item">
                <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>Portfolio
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- copyright text -->
          <div class="copy">
            <p>Copyright &copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</p>
            <p>All rights Reserved</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          isActive: false
        };
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a bit of refactoring. Add a close method:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    },
  },
};
```

Then add it to your main nav button:

```html
<div class="navbar-button" :class="{ 'is-active': isActive }" @click="close">
```

Then to each of your links (simplified):

```html
<router-link to="/" @click="close">
<router-link to="/about" @click="close">
```